# How to access iOS simulator camera

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, ios-camera

I am making a camera app. I need to test the app in the simulator but I can't access the iOS simulator camera.

If not possible in the simulator means I need to access my system camera. Whether it is possible?

I tried `UIImagePickerController` but it doesn't work.

The below the code I've tried.

```
self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];  
UIImagePickerControllerSourceType sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
self.usingPopover = YES;
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
self.usingPopover = NO;
}
[self.imagePicker setSourceType:sourceType];
self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
if (sourceType != UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.imagePicker];
self.popover.delegate = self;
[self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:popoverFrame inView:self.view  
permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
} else {
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];    
}
```

Comment: Try with this repo: https://github.com/YuigaWada/iCimulator. Best Regards

Answer (score 254):

It's not possible to access the camera of your development machine to be used as the simulator camera. Camera functionality is not available in any `iOS` version and in any Simulator. You will have to use a real device for camera testing purposes.

Comment: Wow, that's pathetic, Apple.  And this was never changed since 2014 either?

Comment: Apple is really stupid with this notion, Android's simulator allows me to either use my webcam or just offer a simulated image, you guys can't come up with that and instead ask me to use a real device? Just shows it's all about money and not developers when it comes to Apple.

Comment: I should stop getting surprised by Apple making developers' lives hard. But I still get caught off-guard every time.

Comment: wasted a day pro max plus ultra on this. thank you for clarifying this and now I need to get a used device.

Comment: Until now, I still can't believe this. Good job apple, keep going.. haha

Comment: lool I really can't believe this, is 2023, how in the earth is possible to that you have to pass over all their process to export the app (which is super hard) to simply test your camera ?

Comment: I'm frustrated too because I too wanted to test with it, but I think I see the reasoning... an attacker could use an iOS simulator's camera to sneak up on you. I'm not judging if this is sensible or not, but between them not doing it out of technical incompetence or privacy concerns (they built the machine *and* the simulator you're running it on), I'd stick with the former.

Answer (score 88):

Simulator doesn't have a Camera. If you want to access a camera you need a device. You can't test camera on simulator. You can only check the photo and video gallery.