# iOS 11 Simulator - Safari getUserMedia "invalid constraint"

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, webrtc, ios-simulator

Building a mobile web app and trying to take advantage of the new WebRTC features that dropped with iOS 11, but I seem unable to access the microphone, at least from my XCode iOS 11 simulator (iPhone X)

All requests to `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })` and all other constraint combinations I try result in an `OverconstrainedError` with error message: `Invalid constraint`

I've also verified that the simulator has correct input and output audio devices set. Safari also has rights to microphone and camera in the iOS settings.

To beat a dead horse I have also tried enabling all experimental features in the iOS settings menu for safari to make sure I hadn't missed anything.

Has anyone been able to successfully get the safari mobile browser to collect microphone input in the simulator?

Comment: Have you found a solution so far? If yes, would you mind to create an answer to your question?

Comment: I am having the same issue for ( repo: https://github.com/stephenlb/webrtc-sdk ) on the github repo https://github.com/stephenlb/webrtc-sdk/issues/48 WebRTC SDK  the **simulator is not simulating!!!**

Comment: No, no solution yet @igorpavlov

Comment: @JacksonStone I checked with some people and it is *impossible* to test in iOS Simulator. The simulator does not simply has access to camera/mic. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25486080/how-to-access-ios-simulator-camera

Comment: Thank you @igorpavlov this answers the question.  Apple--